# Django HTML to PDF with links and dynamic data

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf

I have Django 1.7.1 and Python 2.7.8

I want to get a PDF from a rendered html template, I have tried PISA (xhtml2pdf) but first, i had a lot of problems with Bootstrap css, then, after deleting some lines, this message appeared:

```
'CSSTerminalFunction' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

'lower' seems to be part of python 3 and not available in 2.7 (If I am wrong, please tell me)

Now I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf but [the documentation](http://django-wkhtmltopdf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#simple-example) is too basic. It describes only one simple example with static HTML

Can someone explain how I can get a PDF with my actual template?

- In the template, i have 2 links to css files, and one Image (logo)
- I have some bootstrap css style, and i want to use it if possible
- I put a "queryset" (actually a tuple) in the template to be rendered inside a table
- I also put some string parameters to be rendered in deferent locations in my html.

Here is a part of the template

```
{% extends 'reporteBase.html' %}
{% block titulo %}Reporte - Inventario por Ubicación{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% if productos %}
<h2>Inventario de la ubicación "{{ ubi }}"</h2>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 2em">
    <table class="table table-condensed" data-resizable-columns-id="demo-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-resizable-column-id="mod">Modelo/Item</th>
                <th data-resizable-column-id="desc">Descripcion</th>
                <th data-resizable-column-id="cant" data-noresize>Cantidad</th>
                <th data-resizable-column-id="unidad" data-noresize>Unidad</th>
                <th data-resizable-column-id="ubi" data-noresize>Ubicacion</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for p in productos %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ p.producto__item}}</td>
              <td>{{ p.producto__descripcion }}</td>
              <td>{{ p.sum_cantidad }}</td>
              <td>{{ p.producto__unidad }}</td>
              <td>{{ p.ubicacion__nombre }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% empty %}
        <tr><td colspan=4>No hay Productos</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, You want to convert the rendered html to pdf format, not the template.  This looks promising: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xhtml2pdf

Comment: @joelgoldstick I have tried xhtml2pdf already, but it uses a function called 'lower' that it seems not to be in python 2.7, so i need to use another application instead. :/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower

Answer (score 0):

A view needs to render the template as a PDF. That's what the code from the django-wkhtmltopdf [Simple Example](http://django-wkhtmltopdf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#simple-example) does.

Try rendering the page as HTML first to make sure the template is working. You could do this with a view like:

```
url(r'^html_preview/$', 
    TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pdf_template.html'))
```

After you've solved any issues with the template, then try it with `PDFTemplateView`.

Comment: My template works pretty fine, my HTML with all the CSS and Images were rendered exactly the way I want to with the render shortcut, now, I dont know how to put the rendered template in a PDF, actually, I have no idea how to use the PDFTemplate, as far as I know, I need to put only the .html template name and other PDFTemplate parameters, but, how can I put my parameters like the queryset in the template? P.D. thanks for the edit :)

Comment: you need to render the actual web page that shows on your screen, not the django template